# Realm Turn Transaction into observable

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, kotlin

Sometimes i want to perform a write operation after a service call using Retrofit. As my default server calls are performed on the io thread, i just want to use the same thread for the Realm write operation.

I'm using it like this:

```
serviceInteractor.uploadMeasure(measure)
        .filter { uploaded: Boolean -> uploaded } // filter only the ones successfully uploaded
        .flatMap { realmInteractor.markMeasureSent(measure.timeStamp) }
        .subscribe(
                { success -> /* do nothing */ },
                { inDebug { it.printStackTrace() } }
        )
```

My Realm Observable is as follows:

```
fun markMeasureSent(measureId: Long?): Observable<Unit> {
        if (measureId == null) Observable.just(Unit)

        return Observable.fromCallable {
            Realm.getDefaultInstance().use {
                it.executeTransaction { tRealm ->
                    assertNotMainThread()
                    val measure = tRealm.where(Item::class.java)
                            .equalTo(item, measureId)
                            .findFirst()

                    measure.sent = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this the correct way of wrapping a Realm Transaction into an observable?

Comment: It might be a better idea to collect the responses into a list first, and then execute the transaction for the list. But this could also work